# With eclipse, how to hide superclasses methods in Content Assist?

Tags: java, eclipse, filtering, content-assist

For example, I have:

JPanel pan = new JPanel();

then I do "pan." and eclipse shows Content Assist.
In this content assist, there are all methods in JPanel class and all methods in all JPanel superclasses (a lots). I want that eclipse shows me only the methods of the JPanel class, not the methods of its superclasses.

how to do that?

Comment: you want to hide one of the main principle of the object oriented programming?

Comment: when you write code, theory and practice are 2 different things... don't write unuseful comments please...

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515121/eclipse-content-assist) for excluding types permanently

Answer (score 0):

Its not content assist, but you can use Ctrl + O to see all methods of class without superclass.

Comment: hmm.. the outline.. nice but is not what I was looking for.. I hope that there is another solution.. however thanks for the help...