# Eclipse Content Assist

Tags: java, eclipse

When I use Eclipse's Content Assist (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>) I don't want to see the methods inherited from the object class. I searched through the Eclipse [help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tips/jdt_tips.html) but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can [use the type filters](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/preferences/java/appearance/ref-preferences-type-filters.htm) to ignore the class `java.lang.Object`.
This dialog can be found under Preferences -> Java -> Appearance.

[image: Type Filters in Eclipse]